# Is there any possibility that android device screen size does not match with any of generalized size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen

Is there any 0.00001% chance that android device screen size does not match with any of four generalized screen sizes?

If yes, from where will it pick the layout resources, if I don't have defined them in default layout folder?

**Note** I have default layout folder `res/layout/` but don't have all the screens defined in this folder rather defined them in corresponding layout-'screen size' folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any 0.00001% chance that android device screen size does not match with any of four generalized screen sizes?

All devices that legitimately have the Android Market on them will be in one of the four size buckets, or possibly in new buckets defined as part of future versions of Android.

However, there are devices (e.g., WIMM One wearable) that run Android and do not have the Android Market on them. Such devices could, in theory, do something unusual.

> If yes, from where will it pick the layout resources, if I don't have defined them in default layout folder?

You would have to ask the device manufacturer.

> I have default layout folder res/layout/ but don't have all the screens defined in this folder rather defined them in corresponding layout-'screen size' folder.

Generally speaking, it is best to have one of everything in `res/layout`, then *override* them with tailored layouts only where needed (e.g., in `res/layout-large-land/`). If nothing else, this minimizes code duplication.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a great answer. You mean I should define all layout resources in default layout folder too? I was fearing that the android system might half-heartedly pick default layout resources incase it does not find 100% match on screen size. Please throw some light

Comment: @djaqeel: The screen sizes are buckets; by mathematical definition, everything has to be in one of the buckets. Please read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. Btw I am going to copy res/layout-normal resources to default layout folder to be safe..